# Is there a public list of negation and affirmation cues?

Tags: english, negation, resource-request

I am trying to find a public list of "negation" and "affirmation" cues (I'm not a linguist so I apologize if I am using incorrect terminology). A simple example for a "negation cue" I'm looking for is something like:

```
I do NOT have candy
```

Or:

```
There is an ABSENCE of candy
```

Where the capitalized text is negating "I do have candy" and "There is candy", respectively. I see literature that references working with negation cues, but I couldn't find any publicly available word/phrase sets. Does anyone know where I can look for something like this? Thanks.

Comment: This is off-topic, you should consider asking on the English site instead.

Comment: You'll have to trawl through papers such as [this](http://www.sri.com/sites/default/files/publications/detection_of_agreement_and_disagreement_in_broadcast_conversations.pdf) to figure out how they did it. When you're searching on Google Scholar, you'll probably have to search for "agreement and disagreement markers" instead of "negation and affirmation cues".

Comment: @curiousdannii With you see it's off-topic?  [Are data set requests on-topic?](http://meta.linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/1644/2680)